# Reactive when scrolled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basicly I want a div that will move to a different position when i scroll up or down the page. So it could start 30px from the start but as you scroll down it could 100px. as you scroll down more then it will be 60px for example.

The div will be on the right hand side of my page near the middle but as you click a link the page will autoscroll and the div will move to fit the new content.

[edit]I want it to be relative to the browser window so would be fixed right?

So what I want is to be able to have the top tag change value as a scroll to what ever I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create class fixed.
`.fixed{
    position: fixed;
}`
 
And then in jquery you can just add and remove this class depends on scroll position.

Comment: I get that bit but I do not know how to do jquery. I can understand just about when I read it but I can not write it.

adding and removing will not set the new posiotion though would it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with plain JavaScript:

**HTML**

```
<div id="floatingDiv"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#floatingDiv {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {

  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
      floatingDiv = document.getElementById('floatingDiv');

  document.onscroll = function() { 
    floatingDiv.style.top = 30 + Math.round(body.scrollTop / 10) + 'px';
  };

};
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/qewujuhu/2/edit

*Edit:*

**How it works**

Your floating div has an `id` attribute (or `class`, or whatever identifier). In CSS you specify that it's position is relative to browser window (`position:fixed`) and give it initial metrics (width, height, etc.). Once HTML document is fully loaded `window.onload` is called. Inside `window.onload` you find your `<body>` and `<div id="floatingDiv">` elements. After it you define that each time document is scrolled you call a function that sets `style` attribute of `<div id="floatingDiv">` to some value, that contains new `top` for your floating div. This value will override the value in CSS and browser will render div in a new position.

`floatingDiv.style.top = 30 + Math.round(body.scrollTop / 10) + 'px';` means that in the element (that was previously found in the document by `id` attribute) property named `style` (which is also an object) should change value of `top` property to some new value, which is 30px (initial offset that you asked for in the question) plus current vertical scroll position of the page divided by 10 (and rounded since we want to have an integer value, not floating one) concat with string 'px' (which means pixels). As the result of this operation (after scrolling the page 180px down), if you will take a look at the document in development tools you will see something like:

```
<div id="floatingDiv" style="top:48px"></div>
```

Comment: @Mental-State I updated the post with description of how it works.

Comment: thanks but the part I do not get is this  
 floatingDiv.style.top = 30 + Math.round(body.scrollTop / 10) + 'px';